# Why is the background not showing in Tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

So I was implementing the Register page for my website. By the way, for your information, I used `create-react-app` to initialize my project, I use `react-router-dom` for routing and I setup Tailwind CSS using the official documentation as a guide. And then I had a bit of a problem. I added a gradient as the background to make it look fancy and I decided to make a box where the user would type in their username and password in and do some log in stuff. So, I created a `<div>` tag and I applied a background to it. The problem is that the background of the div doesn't show. I assume this is because of the gradient but I don't know, that is why I'm asking. Here's my code so that you can actually debug my problem:

```
const Register = () => {
  return (
    <main className="bg-gradient-to-r from-neutral-blue to-neutral-yellow h-[100vh]">
      <div className="bg-slate-700 w-14 h-14">
        a
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}

export default Register;
```

Thank you for reading and I hope I get an answer that solves my problem soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom colors in your tailwind config? if not you should switch the gradient colors to tailwind colors.

check [this snippet](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mAGo1RCPki) in tailwind play where I got both the `div` and the `main`'s colors to show up by changing the gradient `from` and `to` colors